# What's the correct way to run a website and an API from the same domain/subdomain combination

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am just starting up with Laravel so it's possible that I haven't read through some docs which highlight how possible this is, but here is the requirement.

I have a website, let's call it `https://www.foo.com` , serving HTML to it's visitors.

While a subdomain of it `https://api.foo.com` is supposed to serve a RESTful API.

I am on a GoDaddy hosting and if I create the subdomain, the file structure will look something like this:

```
root/ 
├── website_code/  <- https://www.foo.com
├── ...
├── 
├── api/ <- https://api.foo.com
│   ├── ...
│   ├── 
│   └── ...
└── ...
```

Both will access the same database, and will serve same information, only their format will be different. The API will not need a view, while the HTML version will inject the fetched values into views.

What's the best way to achieve this using Laravel, bearing in mind that:

- The API plans to support OAuth2 and Password Grant type authentication using Passport
- The API may see multiple different version changes in future, with no version being the default choice

Should I run two different Laravel instances under each folder?
Or should I use something like `acceptsJSON()` to ascertain if the `Accept:` header has been set to JSON, and consider it an API request.

Maintaining `api.foo.com` is kind of important for the SEO purposes, but if there's no easy way available, I can look at `https://www.foo.com/api/` format too.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

It totally depends on your need. I would prefer two projects. Suppose in future your website needs to become a single page application then you have to have two different projects. I work on a similar scenario where [Sheba.xyz](https://www.sheba.xyz/)
is a single page application built on vue.js and we use [api.sheba.xyz](https://api.sheba.xyz)
for all the data related works. Again i would say this totally depends on your need. You need to take all your present requirements and future requirements and think which approach is more applicable for you.

Comment: The only concern I have with running two instances, is that the business logic and data that is needed by html and the API, are the same, but with two instances, there will be a lot of redundant code. Is there a way that the two instances can share the same logic written once?